# Participants phone number

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, participants, phone

Some events require the participants' phone numbers. Is there a way to add a field specific to an event?

Answer (score 1):

Include the phone number field in the profile and make it mandatory. Use the profile for doing registration

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. Please note that civicrm is brand new to me. Would you be kind enough to tell me where I can make it "mandatory" only on specific event?

Comment: I thnk Pradeep is suggesting that you use a different Profile for those events, ie set up one Profile for events where phone is not included (or required) and another one for the events where you include AND require the phone field

Comment: and then it may make sense to have to Event Templates, one for 'phone required', one for the other type, and set the relevant Profile on each template so you don't have to remember this each time